# PixateFreestyle Android - App Crash

Tags: pixate

I have successfully imported the pixate freestyle for Android and able to design my buttons.

I am experiencing a app crash problem once I use the following code

```
PixateFreestyle.init(this);
```

It works for the first time, and If I access any activity after using the above code it throws the following runtime exception :

> Caused by: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must
>   be called before adding content
>               at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.requestFeature(PhoneWindow.java:249)

If i remove the code PixateFreestyle.init(this); app is working fine and normal.

Kindly guide me If I am missing anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having the same issue and found that moving my call to `requestWindowFeature()` before the call to `super.onCreate()` fixed it.  Check for any calls that contain `requestFeature` in the activity that is crashing, and make the calls before `super.onCreate()`.

### Example:

**change this:**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
}
```

**to this:**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
```